# iOS Button that performs multiple actions

Tags: ios, facebook, storyboard, segue

I have a button at the end of a guide that says Done!I need it to bring up Facebook posting dialogue and also segue back to the menu screen

At the moment I have it opening a Facebook posting screen, which pops up and goes back down when you click post or cancel. I would like it to return to the menu after the facebook process has completed. I have followed a guide on how segue programatically and have added the code to my current postToFacebook IBAction but it didn't work. I then tried to create it's own IBAction and link it to the button but it didnt work either. 
Does anyone know how I can get it to segue after the Facebook dialogue 
Heres my code for facebook posting in case you need it

```
- (IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender {
mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"I just followed a guide on this App - Get it on the App Store http://"];
[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And heres the code for the programatic segue

```
-(IBAction)nextView{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all code in a single `-(IBAction)` and use a boolean value that changes it's value after executing facebook action.

Something like this,

```
- (IBAction)PostToFacebook:(id)sender {
    if(valueOfBoolean==TRUE){
        mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"I just followed a guide on this App - Get it on the App Store http://"];
        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
        valueOfBoolean=FALSE;
    }
    else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Set default value for `valueOfBoolean` as `TRUE` in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Okay, I've got it working almost how I want it. What's happening is that when you click the button once it brings up the facebook dialogue, then you close the dialogue and it is still on the same screen, click the button for the second time and it will segue. Is there any way to make it all happen with one press?

Comment: you can add long press action to button :-/ that uses a method in which  you use [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];

Answer (score 0):

EDITED :

```
   - (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender {


    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *facebook = [[SLComposeViewController alloc]init];

        facebook = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [facebook setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your string"]];
        [self presentViewController:facebook animated:YES completion:nil];

        [facebook setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            NSString *output;
            switch (result) {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    // here you can handle your seque, or your custom action what you want
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    // here you can handle your seque, or your custom action what you want
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            //            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        }];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Account" message:@"There are no Facebook accounts configured. You can configure or create accounts in settings ." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}
```

I hope it helps !

Comment: Sorry but where do I put this?

Comment: I tried it, and it only does the Facebook posting, not the segue